# Tensorflow Python: Method for multi-class labels

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the Abalone Dataset (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Abalone) and it has data of certain abalones, with features such as sex, diameter, length, and weight.
I want to be able to use the diameter, length, and weight features to predict the sex either, Male, Female, and Infant (you thought its 2019).

I am currently doing it so that I am simply replacing every M with 0,F with 1 and I with 2. From what I've learned this is a dense encoding it works perfectly fine from what I'm doing. But I want to use something called one-hot encoding I've tried multiple things, but I keep getting dimension errors and can't find any resources on it.

My current method:

```py
abalone_dataframe = pd.read_csv("abalone.csv")
abalone_dataframe.dropna()
abalone_dataframe = abalone_dataframe.reindex(np.random.permutation(abalone_dataframe.index))
#Male 0, Female 1, Infant 2
mapping = {"M" : 0, "F" : 1, "I" : 2}
abalone_dataframe = abalone_dataframe.replace({"sex" : mapping})
abalone_dataframe
```

How can I make it so I use one-hot encoding instead of a dense mapping?

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
sex_label = abalone_dataframe['sex'].values
sex_label_onehot = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False).fit_transform(sex_label .reshape(-1,1))
```

Comment: This does give me the appropriate one-hot encoding but how do I exaclty use this for tensorflow, I do use sklearn but I need to be able to transform into some sort tensorflow data so I can use it for my `input_fn` function. Thank you for answering though~